# From JSON string to object

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have a following valid json string:

```
var result = "[{\"total\":" + wpTotal + ",\"totalpages\":" + wpTotalPages + "},{\"tags\":[{\"id\":384},{\"id\":385}]}]";
```

I am trying to use this method to deserialize it to object of type T:

```
public static T FromJSON<T>(string json)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
            {
                UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true
            };
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
```

And using it like this:

```
var obj = JsonHelper.FromJSON<TagsResponse>(result);
```

I am always getting empty result (null) without any exception or any kind of information.

My model is:

```
[DataContract]
public class TagsResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "totalpages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "tags")]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: can you try `var obj = JsonHelper.FromJSON<TagsResponse[]>(result);` ?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered using a library such as Json.NET for serialisation/deserialisation?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I can't use Json.NET in case of back compatibility

Comment: @tym32167 after some edits and adding `[]` I am getting two objects with not all properties properly set.

Comment: this is because your json isnt correct. Try `var result = "[{\"total\":" + wpTotal + ",\"totalpages\":" + wpTotalPages + ",\"tags\":[{\"id\":384},{\"id\":385}]}]";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with the format of your input, the properties in the json string are not the expected level of your objects, here is a working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{\"total\":" + 1 + ",\"totalpages\":" + 10 + ",\"tags\":[{\"id\":384},{\"id\":385}]}";
        var result = json.FromJSON<TagsResponse>();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + result);
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static T FromJSON<T>(this string json)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class TagsResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "totalpages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "tags")]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Tag
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the `FromJSON` method and when using it like that: `var obj = JsonHelper.FromJSON<TagsResponse[]>(result);` I am getting two objects (I am expecting one), one with List equals null but with properties and second properites are null but list is OK

Answer (score 1):

1) Create correct json

```
var result = "[{\"total\":" + wpTotal + ",\"totalpages\":" + wpTotalPages + ",\"tags\":[{\"id\":384},{\"id\":385}]}]";
```

2) Parse it as array

```
var obj = JsonHelper.FromJSON<TagsResponse[]>(result);
```

**Or**, if you want to parse it as single item, you can remove [] from json

```
var result = "{\"total\":" + wpTotal + ",\"totalpages\":" + wpTotalPages + ",\"tags\":[{\"id\":384},{\"id\":385}]}";
var obj = JsonHelper.FromJSON<TagsResponse>(result);
```